# Removing doubles from An array

Tags: java, arrays

I just started coding LeetCode problmes. The problem is the following:
Given a sorted array, remove the duplicates in place such that each element appear only once and return the new length.

Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this in place with constant memory.

My solution is the following:

```
public static int removeDuplicates1(int[] A) {
        Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for(Integer i: A){
            mySet.add(i);
        }
        return mySet.size();
    }
```

Even though I get the right answer in Eclipse, my answer was not accepted by the website. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: "_Do not allocate extra space for another array_" You did this when you created `mySet`.

Comment: If you made a new set, then you're allocating extra space, no?

Comment: But besides that condition, This solution would work right? @Takendarkk

Comment: You get the right answer yes. You just used more memory than the problem wants.

Comment: @Takendarkk thank you, I finally got the solution without allocating more memory

Comment: @Alexander Feel free to answer your own question if you have the solution

Comment: There are 2 parts in the excercise: 1) Remove duplicates 2) Return new length. You didn't fulfill 1). (I guess the array should be modified to contain the elements without duplicates in the first *return value* elements)

Answer (score 0):

if the array is sorted, you can directly compare consecutive elements for duplicates until you find a different element.Once the loop is completed you can return the new length using array length property.

Obviously you have to manage your logic at some places for doing the same.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this with below logic. It is not in place array allocation though. Still not sure how to remove null from an array with in place logic.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

            Integer[] initArray = { 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
            System.out.println("Initial Array : "+ Arrays.toString(initArray));

            System.out.println("Array Size After  Duplicates Removal : "+ removeDuplicates(initArray));
        }

    public static int removeDuplicates(Integer[] arr) {

        Integer prev = null;
        for(int index= 0; index <= arr.length -1;  index ++){
            if(arr[index] == prev)
            {
                remove(index, arr);
                prev = arr[index];
            }else{
                prev = arr[index];
                continue;
            }
        }

        List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>(arr.length);
        for(Integer input : arr) {
           if (input != null) {
              items.add(input);
           }
        }
        Integer[] outputs = items.toArray(new Integer[items.size()]);
        System.out.println("Final Array : "+ Arrays.toString(outputs));
        return outputs.length;
    }

    public static void remove(int index, Integer[] a){

        int lastIndex = a.length-1;
        if(index <= lastIndex){
            a[index] =null;
            int tmp = index;
            while(tmp < lastIndex){
                a[tmp] = a[tmp+1];
                a[tmp+1] = null;
                tmp++;
            }
            lastIndex--;
        } else {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't even come close to answering the question. The question is "_Why is my solution not being accepted by LeetCode?_"